# Select buttons with a mouse rather then keyboard

Tags: java, button, menu

Hi I made a pause menu for my game, and you navigate through it with the arrow keys on the keyboard. My question is how do I make it so I can navigate with my mouse, and click the buttons rather then having to use the arrow keys?

here is the code:

```
public class InGameMenu implements KeyListener {

private String[] string = { "Resume Game", "Options", "Save Game", "Load Game", "Exit Game" };
private String[] optionStrings = { "Help", "Back" };

public static int selected = 0;
private int space = 25;

public int width = 800;
public int height = 600;

public static boolean isInMenu = true;
public static boolean isInOptions = false;
public static boolean saving = false;
public static boolean loading = false;

public InGameMenu() {

}

public void tick() {

}

public void render(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 90));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, Component.width, Component.height);
    if (isInMenu) {
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        if (saving) {
            g.drawString("Saving", Component.width / 2 / Component.pixelSize - (int) (Component.width / 25), 35);
        }
        if (loading) {
            g.drawString("Loading", Component.width / 2 / Component.pixelSize - (int) (Component.width / 25), 35);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
            if (selected == i) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            g.drawString(string[i], Component.width / 2 / Component.pixelSize - (int) (Component.width / 17.5), Component.height / 8 + (i * space));
        }
    } else if (isInOptions) {
        for (int i = 0; i < optionStrings.length; i++) {
            if (selected == i) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            g.drawString(optionStrings[i], Component.width / 2 / Component.pixelSize - (int) (Component.width / 17.5), Component.height / 8 + (i * space));

        }
    }

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (isInMenu) {
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            selected--;
            if (selected < 0) {
                selected = string.length - 1;
            }
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            selected++;
            if (selected > string.length - 1) {
                selected = 0;
            }
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            if (selected == 0) {
                Component.isInMenu = false;
            } else if (selected == 1) {
                isInMenu = false;
                isInOptions = true;
                selected = 0;
            } else if (selected == 2) {
                saving = true;
                SaveLoad.save();
                saving = false;
            } else if (selected == 3) {
                loading = true;
                SaveLoad.load();
                loading = false;
            } else if (selected == 4) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    } else if (isInOptions) {
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            selected--;
            if (selected < 0) {
                selected = optionStrings.length - 1;
            }
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            selected++;
            if (selected > optionStrings.length - 1) {
                selected = 0;
            }
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            if (selected == 0) {
                System.out.println("HELP");
            } else if (selected == 1) {
                isInOptions = false;
                isInMenu = true;
            }
        }
    }

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `MouseListener` too.

You can add these methods from `MouseListener`:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource() == button1)
    {
        isInMenu = false;
        isInOptions = true;
        selected = 0;
    }
    if(e.getSource() == button2)
    {
        saving = true;
        SaveLoad.save();
        saving = false;
    }
    if(e.getSource() == button3)
    {
        loading = true;
        SaveLoad.load();
        loading = false;
    }
    if(e.getSource() == button4)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

}
```

Comment: `getButton` specifies *which* mouse button was pressed. It does not determine *where* the press occured. Did you test this? How does this determine which item was selected?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Nice catch! Sorry, about that. I'll fix it.

Comment: Tip: Suggest using `Font` so they can use `FontMetrics` to [measure the text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html). Using the `getWidth` and `getHeight` from metrics, plus the `x` and `y` position of the text, you can check whether the mouse has clicked in that area.

Comment: did anyone find a solution?

Comment: @Artem Yeah, check out my answer. Coffeehouse, you may want to check it out too

Answer (score 0):

## First, you must get the bounds (`x`, `y`, `width` and `height`) of the text.

You already have the `x` and `y`:

```
g.drawString(string[i], Component.width / 2 / Component.pixelSize - (int) (Component.width / 17.5), Component.height / 8 + (i * space));
// x = Component.width / 2 / Component.pixelSize - (int) (Component.width / 17.5)
// y = Component.height / 8 + (i * space)
```

You can determine the `width` and `height` via `Font#getStringBounds(String, FontRenderContext)`:

```
FontRenderContext renderContext = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14);
String labelText = "Start";

Rectangle2D labelBounds = font.getStringBounds(labelText, renderContext);
int labelWidth = (int) labelBounds.getWidth();
int labelHeight = (int) labelBounds.getHeight();
```

The bounds is needed to determine if the mouse is hovering over the text when the click occurs.

## Next, you must maintain the bounds for each menu item.

Right now, you're only maintaining the names in `string` and `optionStrings`. You'll need to maintain the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` for every menu item.

Since every menu item each has their own name, size and position, it would be easier to create a new type composed of these properties:

```
public class Label {    
    private String name;
    private Font font;
    private int x, y;
    private int width, height;

    public Label(String name, Font font, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.font = font;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

Instead of a `String[]`, you could have a `Label[]`. Although it's preferrable to use `List` for it's higher-level functionality:

```
public class InGameMenu implements MouseListener {
    private List<Label> labels;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        int x = event.getX();
        int y = event.getY();

        labels.forEach(label -> {
        //  if (mouse hovering over label)
        //     ...
        });
    }
}
```

## Then, you must determine if the mouse position is within the label's position.

The formula is pretty simple:

```
// checks if mouse intersects with label on X axis
intersectsHorizontally := mouseX > labelX && mouseX < labelX + labelWidth;

// checks if mouse intersects with label on Y axis
intersectsVertically := mouseY > labelY && mouseY < labelY + labelHeight;

// if both conditions above are true, mouse is hovering over label
```

The easiest way to implement this would be to give your `Label` objects a `containsPoint(int x, int y)` behavior:

```
public class Label {
    private int x, y;
    private int width, height;

    //...

    public boolean containsPoint(int pointX, int pointY) {
        boolean containsHorizontally = pointX > x && pointX < x + width;
        boolean containsVertically = pointY > y && pointY < y + height;

        return containsHorizontally && containsVertically;
    }
}
```

Now you can easily determine whether the mouse is hovering over a specific label:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    int x = event.getX();
    int y = event.getY();

    labels.forEach(label -> {
        if(label.containsPoint(x, y)) {
            //...
        }
    });
}
```

## Finally, you must determine *which* label was clicked

There are many ways to go about this. Instead of a `List`, you could maintain the labels independently and check each one:

```
public class InGameMenu implements MouseListener {
    private Label startLabel;
    private Label loadLabel;

    public InGameMenu(Label startLabel, Label loadLabel) {
         this.startLabel = startLabel;
         this.loadLabel = loadLabel;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        int x = event.getX();
        int y = event.getY();

        if(startLabel.containsPoint(x, y)) {
            //start game
        } else if(loadLabel.containsPoint(x, y)) {
            //load game
        }
    }
}
```

But this isn't dynamic, as `InGameMenu` is forced to know about every label it has, and adding labels would be a pain.

A better approach is to create all the `Label` objects outside of `InGameMenu`, as the examples above have been doing:

```
FontRenderContext renderContext = ...;
Font font = ...;

// start label
String labelText = "Start";
Rectangle2D labelBounds = font.getStringBounds(labelText, renderContext);
int x = ...;
int y = ...;
int width = (int) labelBounds.getWidth();
int height = (int) labelBounds.getHeight();
Label label = new Label(labelText, font, labelX, labelY, labelWidth, labelHeight);

// list of all labels for menu
List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<>();
labels.add(label);

InGameMenu menu = new InGameMenu(labels);
```

Then have the label object tell us when it has been clicked. We can do this by giving `Label` a `click()` method for `InGameMenu` to trigger when the label has been clicked:

```
public class InGameMenu implements MouseListener {
    private List<Label> labels;

    public InGameMenu(List<Label> labels) {
        this.labels = labels;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        int x = event.getX();
        int y = event.getY();

        labels.forEach(label -> {
            if(label.containsPoint(x, y))
                label.click();
        });
    }
}
```

Then allowing `Label` to accept a callback function:

```
public class Label {    
    private String name;
    private Font font;
    private int x, y;
    private int width, height;
    private Runnable onClick;

    public Label(String name, Font font, int x, int y, int width, int height, Runnable onClick) {
        this.name = name;
        this.font = font;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.onClick = onClick;
    }

    public void click() {
        onClick.run();
    }

    //...
}
```

So when you create `Label` objects, you can give them actions that make use of outside data (maybe a `GameStateManager` or something):

```
Runnable onClick = () -> System.out.println("Start button was clicked!");

Label label = new Label("Start", ..., onClick);
```